# how to clone a GitLab repo

Tags: git, gitlab, git-clone

I have a GitLab Community Edition up and am staggering forward :)

- Pushing to repos - DONE
- Pulling from public repos - DONE
- Cloning public repos - DONE

if I try to make the repo's private or internal, I am no longer able to clone (as should be, out-of-the-box)

But how, for Pete's sake, am I to "cap production deploy" (as say 'web-user') and have this user on web-server call up git-server and clone a repo?

I've tried setting up deploy-ssh's on GitLab, but that seems to be dedicated to the GitLab CI (which I'm yet to embark) :)

Comment: The adding a deploy key with the public ssh key of your web-user should work. It's not just intended for GitLab CI.

Comment: @twk3 you are most certainly right! I realized that my gitlab and my app-server are both sitting behind a firewall - and hitting the gitserver on its public FQDN did nothing good to the 'smalltalk' - your kind 'push in the back' was just what I needed! Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab repos have 3 settings - pertaining to the users eligible to clone them - private, internal and public. Adding the deploy user from your Capfile (or which ever way you need access to the repo) and then logging in as that user and adding its public SSH key will get you to the repo - provided you hit the gitlab server on it's correct IP-address!

My question - it turned out - really was not about accessing GitLab correctly, but hitting 10.0.x.x-something instead of gitserver.some-domain.tld, from some other 10.0.x.x app-server!